# Wordpress post or taxonomy relationship?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called "Podcast" with (fields) author (the artist who made the podcast),description and a custom taxonomy "Genre" with terms like "Elettronica","House",ecc.
When i'll click the field Author i want to open a new page with the author's biography and all his podcast.
So, the question is: should author be a custom post type or a custom taxonomy?
I don't understand how relationship work in Wordpress.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, The author is just a user why it has to be a custom post type or a custom taxonomy? use usermeta to connect the user with the podcasts IDs that belong to.

Comment: The author is the 'artist' who made the podcast, it's not a wordpress user.  I didn't express myself clearly enough, sorry. Now i fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author should be taxonomy, it's not a problem to assign a post to mutiple taxonomies. Spend some time on checking what tags are in Wordpress and best practices to use it all along with categories.

Comment: Thank you for your help